"unknown option: --bash" when opening the terminal
Whenever I open the terminal, I get the following line as the first line in the terminal:
unknown option: --bash

Here is a screenshot of my terminal:

Here is my ~/.bashrc file:
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'


# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/harshalc03/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/harshalc03/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/harshalc03/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/harshalc03/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

[ -f ~/.fzf.bash ] && source ~/.fzf.bash

And here is .fzf.bash, since it seems related:
# Setup fzf
# ---------
if [[ ! "$PATH" == */home/harshalc03/.fzf/bin* ]]; then
  PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}/home/harshalc03/.fzf/bin"
fi

eval "$(fzf --bash)"

I have searched online but there were no solutions to this issue. Can you please help?

eval "$(fzf --bash)"  is the problem. fzf is empty.

To use fzf you just type fzf --query [query] and it will do a search.

@ArturMeinild But I don't want to type fzf --query everytime. Ctrl+R just does this if fzf is on. And in my case even when the command was there, it just stuck with reverse-i-search

The problem is inside ~/.fzf.bash.
I'm not sure what this is supposed to do (or why you would run it in your .bashrc), but the command:
eval "$(fzf --bash)"

Gives that error message, since --bash isn't a valid parameter to the fzf command.
So remove or otherwise fix this invalid command.

Yes, removing the line solves the issue but I want to integrate fuzzyfinder in my terminal: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.
How will I do it then? @Rinzwind

As @Artur said in his answer, the issue is the --bash parameter in eval "$(fzf --bash)". More specifically, if you look at fzf's GitHub page, you will see the following note:

--bash, --zsh, and --fish options are only available in fzf 0.48.0 or later. If you have an older version of fzf, or want finer control, you can source individual script files in the /shell directory. The location of the files may vary depending on the package manager you use. Please refer to the package documentation for more information. (e.g. apt show fzf)

So you are most likely using an fzf version that does not support this option (run fzf --version and see; you should get a version < 0.48). This can happen if you have installed fzf using apt, which for Ubuntu 24.04 is 0.44, or if you have an old git installation of fzf, for which you haven't pulled the latest changes.
In any case, to install the latest version of fzf, which allows for shell integration using the --bash option, follow these steps:

Remove the version installed using apt:
sudo apt remove fzf


Remove the ~/.fzf directory if it exists and install fzf using git:
rm -rf ~/.fzf
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ~/.fzf
~/.fzf/install


Run fzf --version. You should now see:
$ fzf --version
0.52.1 (6432f00)


Restore your ~/.bashrc file, since eval "$(fzf --bash)" should now work.


That's it! fzf should now work properly with the keybindings enabled! In the future, if you want to update fzf, you can use the following command:
cd ~/.fzf && git pull && ./install


Thank you very much, this works.

You're welcome! :)

no clue why i had the fedora installed fzf version, but your solution helped me realize  that i wasn't using the submodule from my dotfiles, so thank you!!
